# when loading webpage in webview using android not rendring properly

Tags: android

{wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

```
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        //wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptCUInterface(this), "CG");

        //wv.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) solution go to xml layout and set webview width and height fill parent.
 
2) your website is not responsive. please check.

Comment: XML is <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/web_header_id" /><br/> but in tablet and IOS it's working fine.

Comment: please tell me your url to open in webview

Comment: Your website is not responsive your coding is right. You check responsive open this link in firefox and press ctrl+shift+M and check the different size device. If u like this solution please upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");

Fixed the loading issue by hard coding the user agent to iPhone user agent. I am searching for a better solution, but it worked for now.